# Power Switch for 60V and 120A DC

Tags: voltage, power, amplifier, switches

This forum is super awesome! I have been creeping around it for almost 6 months and decided to become a part of it to ask a question I had.

So, I am trying to build a on and off switch on my electric scooter. I need the switch to be able to power on and off up to 60VDC and 120Amp and  I am a starving student so  I  am hoping its under $20 ( that's about 40 - 80 ramen meals depending on where you source them :D )

Thanks in advance !

Comment: I'll give you 6 ramen if you do some preliminary research.

Comment: This is a [shopping question](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) and is off-topic here.

Comment: May not have the voltage rating you need, but you can take a look at starter solenoids for automobiles. They are designed to switch large DC currents.

Comment: And sometimes are available in junk yards (scrap heaps).

Comment: but most of these starter solenoids are designed for low duty cycle

Comment: @Kaywerks: You don't want an on/off switch - you want a variable speed controller so you can control the acceleration. An on/off switch will give you a 7.2 kW kick in the pants and you'll be lucky to be able to hold on to the handlebars.

Comment: @ElectronS, they can't be cycled, you are right about that. The OP said "on and off switch" which I took to be a master switch. I think it is OK to leave a solenoid on continuously, but it definitely cannot be cycled for speed control.

Comment: @mkeith , no no no , you cannot leave it ON for a prolonged time even if it is a master swith , couple of weeks ago i bought 1 of these , it is a truck starter solenoid , after leaving it for 1 hour ON on a current limited power supply ( it consumes 1.7A continous ) the coil shorted out and it got so hot that you could literally melt solder on the outer case

Comment: @ElectronS, well, that doesn't sound good. So that idea is probably a loser.

Comment: @ElectronS, after searching a little, I think continuous duty solenoids exist, but I don't think they are likely to be found in a scrap pile.

Comment: @mkeith , bravo +1 for the search ! they do exist and companies like albrightinternational have been making them along with short duty . but offcourse for a starter motor every manufacturer is going to choose the low duty due to small wieght and lower cost. regards :)

Answer (score 1):

Something I would be cautious about is the inductive nature of any electric engine. Switching off a live circuit with inductive components will result in voltage spikes, and therefore electric arcs that can easily kill any switch and possibly even damage other components in the circuit. I recommend you watch [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LXGtE3X2k7Y) for further information on that topic.

Before trying to install a switch, I recommend trying to reverse engineer the power electronics in your scooter to make sure there are adequate protections against this, and if not, adding a [flyback diode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flyback_diode) to the engine should probably be enough to protect the circuit. I assume you are an EE student? It'll probably be a good exercise to try to figure out how your scooter works, just make sure to be safe and disconnect the battery before doing anything.

Now, as for selecting an appropriate switch, you can search suppliers like [digikey](http://www.digikey.pt/product-search/en/switches/) and do a parametric search for the appropriate voltage and current ratings. However, depending where you live, shipping costs will probably be very prohibitive and it'll probably be much cheaper if you just search for local electronics suppliers and personally ask them if they have switches that meet your criteria. You can always use ebay, but be on the lookout for dodgy parts.